# How to influence the order of cascaded generators?

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I want to use source generators more in my project.
Something that I need to often do, is generate code that is then utilised by another generator.

For example.

I have written a generator that produces a dart file from a swagger json schema.
That dart file is annotated with @JsonSerializable - so it should then trigger a serializer to be generated.

In this simple case it more of less works - however I think that's mostly down to the luck of the draw.

There are more complex scenarios, such as ones that utilise the MobX generator - these appear extremely flakey and often break when things are not generated in the correct order. Sometimes I need to just "touch" a specific file in a particular way to either break or fix the build runner.

Has this scenario been considered in the design of the source_gen subsystem, and how do I ensure this is working correctly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to ensure that your generators are executed in the correct order because the orders in which generators run can sometimes affect the outcome.

You can use the `build.yaml` file to specify the order in which generators should run.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      your_generator1:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**/*.dart
      your_generator2:
        generate_for:
          - generated/**/*.dart  # Depend on the output of your_generator1
```

Here is a real-world sample:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      flutter_api|apiParser:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - lib/basic_api/generated/*_receive.json
      flutter_api|api:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - lib/basic_api/generated/*_send.json
          - lib/basic_api/generated/*_receive.json
      flutter_api|apiHelper:
        enabled: true

builders:
  apiParser:
    import: "./api_parser.dart"
    builder_factories: ["apiParser"]
    auto_apply: root_package
    build_extensions: { ".json": ["_result.dart"] }
    is_optional: False
    build_to: source
    runs_before:
      - flutter_api|api
    defaults:
      generate_for:
        include:
          - lib/basic_api/generated/*_receive.json

  api:
    import: "./api_builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["apiBuilder"]
    auto_apply: root_package
    build_extensions: { ".json": [".dart"] }
    is_optional: False
    build_to: source
    runs_before:
      - flutter_api|apiHelper
    defaults:
      generate_for:
        include:
          - lib/basic_api/generated/**

  apiHelper:
    import: "./api_helper_builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["apiHelperBuilder"]
    build_extensions: { ".dart": [".helper.dart"] }
    is_optional: False
    build_to: source
    required_inputs: ["api"]
    runs_before:
      - json_serializable
    defaults:
      generate_for:
        include:
          - lib/basic_api/helper/response_mapper.dart
```

Comment: Thank you @Hamed. I have a build.yaml in my generators project - however my actual application project is where I have the issue (because I'm using a collection of my own generators, and 3rd party ones, like JsonSerializable) - is it still valid to put a build.yaml file in an application project?

Comment: I am not sure but I suppose it is valid you have to check this.

Comment: Thanks again @Hamed - after trying this out, all I needed was to use "runs_before" to ensure my generator had completed so it would be picked up as input to 3rd party generators. Thank you again!